# How to save user-generated data to the user in Firebase using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to create a todo list with Firebase. After a user authenticates with Google, the user can create tasks, but I can't figure out how to store the task to the user.

I'm trying to use `.child()`, but I can't know what the uid is for each user is. I also tried `.orderByChild()`, but that doesn't seem to do it , either (or I'm not using it right).

I've tried:

```
var firebase = new Firebase('https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com');

firebase.child('users').child(authData.uid).child('task').push({
            status: 'In Progress',
            taskName: $taskName.val(),
            taskDescription: $taskDescription.val(),
            taskCategory: $taskCategory.val()
        })
```

authData.uid is given by Google on authentication:

```
firebase.authWithOAuthPopup('google', function(error, authData) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
                } else {
                    // Stores user in Firebase
                    firebase.onAuth(function(authData) {
                        if (authData) {
firebase.child('users').child(authData.uid).set({
                                name: authData.google.displayName
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the minimal-but-complete code that shows the problem please. There is too much room for interpretation with the tiny inline snippets. If you find it difficult to isolate the problem in such a way, try reproducing it in a jsfiddle/jsbin first and add the link and crucial code to your question. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your snippet seems perfectly fine. What is the problem? What would you like to do that doesn't work ? `firebase.child('users').child(authData.uid).child('task').push(...)` would create a new node under users/$uid/task. Is it not what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the task, you build the path like this:

```
firebase.child('users').child(authData.uid).child('task').push({
```

That won't work, because `authData` is not available anymore at this point.

Instead you can get the current auth data by calling `ref.getAuth()` and do:

```
var uid = firebase.getAuth().uid;
firebase.child('users').child(uid).child('task').push({
```

Note that this is covered in the [guide on Firebase Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication) and I highly recommend reading it.

Comment: That was it! Thank you, Frank!